# create array list of instances of annotated classes

Tags: java, list, class, reflection

I have a problem with creating an arraylist of instances. I got a `Set<Class<?>>` and then I check if they implement a specific interface. If they do I want to add an instance of this class to an arraylist of the specific interface.

This is my code:

```
ArrayList<MyInterface> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (Class clazz : annotatedClasses) {
    if(MyInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
        Object instance = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
        list.add(object); //ERROR: Object != MyInterface
    }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: also not sure if this is related to your problem but..... your variables dont match `Object instance.....list.add(object)`. You created a varaible called `instance` then added a variable called `object`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should cast the result of `newInstance` to the wanted type. You know that this is not going to throw a [`ClassCastException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) because you just checked that it is assignable.

```
List<MyInterface> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (Class<?> clazz : annotatedClasses) {
    if (MyInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
        Object instance = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
        list.add((MyInterface) instance);
    }
}
```

However, beware that this can throw an exception if the class does not have a default constructor.

Comment: You should use a generic for `Class` in the for loop.

Answer (score 4):

You have to cast it to your interface

```
Object instance = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
list.add((MyInterface)instance);
```

Could also be written as

```
MyInterface instance = (MyInterface) clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
list.add(instance);
```